# При передвижении объект оставляет след

Tags: javascript, html, css, canvas

```
var game = {
  sprites: {
    battleship: undefined,
    enemyShip: undefined
  },

  init: function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    this.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
      if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        game.battleship.x -= 8
      } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        game.battleship.x += 8
      }
      this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    })
  },

  load: function() {
    for (var key in this.sprites) {
      this.sprites[key] = new Image();
      this.sprites[key].src = "sprites/" + key + ".png";
    }
  },

  start: function() {
    this.init();
    this.load();
    this.run();
  },

  render: function() {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    this.ctx.drawImage(this.sprites.battleship, this.battleship.x, this.battleship.y, 68, 68);
    this.ctx.drawImage(this.sprites.enemyShip, this.enemyShip.x, this.enemyShip.y, 60, 60);
  },

  run: function() {
    this.render();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      game.run();
    });
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
  }
};

game.battleship = {
  x: 355,
  y: 520
}

game.enemyShip = {
  x: 355,
  y: -10,
  grav: 1
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  game.start()
});
```

Comment: а зачем делать clearRect и до и после render?

Answer (score 1):

Объект оставлял след из-за того, что `this.width` и `this.height` не выставлены.

Соответственно при `this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);` чистится область `0px` на `0px`

```js
var game = {
  
  width: 0,
  height: 0,
  
  
  sprites: {
    battleship: undefined,
    enemyShip: undefined
  },

  init: function() {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
    this.ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    
    // Т.к. при очистке полотна идёт обращение к this.width и this.height
    // их нужно выставить равными размеру полотна которое мы чистим
    this.width = canvas.width;
    this.height = canvas.height;
    
    window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
      if (event.keyCode == 37) {
        game.battleship.x -= 8
      } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
        game.battleship.x += 8
      }
    })
  },

  load: function() {
    for (var key in this.sprites) {
      this.sprites[key] = new Image();
      this.sprites[key].src = 
        `https://via.placeholder.com/50x50.png?text=${key}`
        //"sprites/" + key + ".png";
    }
  },

  start: function() {
    this.init();
    this.load();
    this.run();
  },

  render: function() {
    
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    this.ctx.drawImage(this.sprites.battleship, this.battleship.x, this.battleship.y, 68, 68);
    this.ctx.drawImage(this.sprites.enemyShip, this.enemyShip.x, this.enemyShip.y, 60, 60);
  },

  run: function() {
    this.render();

    window.requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      game.run();
      // Зачем чистить экран сразу после того как отрисовали?
      //this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height);
    });
  }
};

game.battleship = {
  x: 10,
  y: 10
}

game.enemyShip = {
  x: 355,
  y: -10,
  grav: 1
}

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
  game.start()
});
```

```css
canvas{
  border:1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Спасибо огромноее!!!!